# Swift: How can I make a function with a Subclass return type conform to a protocol, where a Superclass is defined as a return type?

Tags: swift, oop, protocols

I have a protocol, where a function is defined, the return type of a function is a `SuperclassType`.

In a class which conforms to the protocol I'm trying to define this function, but with a `SubclassType` return type.

Compiler tells me, that this class does not conform to the protocol, because obviously `SubclassType` != `SuperclassType`

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
  func someFunction(someParameter:SomeType) -> SuperclassType?
}

class SomeClass : SomeProtocol {
  func someFunction(someParameter:SomeType) -> SubclassType? {
    ...
  }
}

class SubclassType : SuperclassType { }
```

Common sense tells me, though, that `SubclassType` should be a suitable substitute for a `SuperclassType` in this matter.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before you go much further, I'd recommend some background reading on [covariance vs contravariance](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html) and the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

- Return types for methods *overridden when subclassing* are **covariant**: the subclass override of a method can return a *subtype* of the superclass method's return type.
- Generic type parameters are **invariant**: a specialization can neither narrow nor expand the type requirements.

The relationship between a protocol and a concrete type that adopts it is more like generics than like subclassing, so return types declared in protocols are invariant, too. (It's hard to say exactly why on first read. Possibly something about existential vs constraint-only protocols?)

You can allow covariance in a protocol by specifying associated type requirements, though:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype ReturnType: SuperclassType
    func someFunction(someParameter: SomeType) -> ReturnType
}

class SomeClass : SomeProtocol {
    func someFunction(someParameter: SomeType) -> SubclassType { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now, it's clear that the return type of `someFunction` in a type adopting `SomeProtocol` must be either `SuperclassType` or a subtype thereof.

Comment: Type parameters of methods in protocols are invariant from protocol to the adopting superclass, but they are contravariant from superclass to subclass.

Comment: It's worth noting that adding an `associatedtype` greatly restricts the number of ways you can use the protocol (much to my annoyance) - it's disbarred from being a function parameter type, generic parameter type, variable type, you can't return one from a function, and you can't make an array of them.  Probably most other things, too.