# How do you structure generic type protocol conformance in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

The following contrived Swift 2 example from real-world code won't compile:

```
protocol SomeModelType {  }

protocol SomeProtocol {
    var someVar: SomeModelType? { get }
}

class ConcreteClass<T: SomeModelType>: SomeProtocol {
    var someVar: T?
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me fully. I would assume in `ConcreteClass` that because I have `T` being constrained to `SomeModelType` and have `T` as the backing type for the `someVar` property, the compiler would be able to figure out that the `SomeProtocol` was being conformed to by `ConcreteClass`.

How should an example like this be structured? **Is it possible to the Swift compiler to determine protocol conformance through generic type constraints?**

Comment: Related (possible dupe?): [Swift: How can I make a function with a Subclass return type conform to a protocol, where a Superclass is defined as a return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094967/swift-how-can-i-make-a-function-with-a-subclass-return-type-conform-to-a-protoc) Your problem has very little to do with generics, it's due to the fact that protocol requirements must be satisfied in an invariant manner (as the linked Q&A says) – therefore you cannot satisfy an abstract type requirement with a concrete type that conforms to that abstract type.

Comment: This may seem counter-intuitive, but remember that allowing covariant behaviour for protocol conforming would break with contravariant relationships (e.g property setters and method inputs). Casting a `ConcreteClass<XYZ>` to `SomeProtocol` would allow for *anything* that conforms to `SomeModelType` to be inputted into parameters that previously had a concrete type, which would be illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protocol SomeModelType {  }

protocol SomeProtocol {

    associatedtype T: Any
    var someVar: T? { get }
}

class ConcreteClass<T> :SomeProtocol where T: SomeModelType {

    var someVar: T?

}
```