# Swift Compiler lose its polymorphical context

Tags: swift, oop, swift5

First, I'm new to Swift language and have worked using python which is 'dynamic typed' language, so don't know exact compiler's perspective.

Below code is a simple code snippet to practice what Apple said POP(protocol oriented programming).
Snippet contains various **ReturnClasses**, **RunnerClasses**(each has different return type) and actual runner which just run **RunnerClasses**. Also has **Selector** enum to pretend dynamic dispatch.

```swift
protocol Return {
    var value: Int { get set }
    init(_ value: Int)
}

final class Return0: Return {
    var value: Int
    init(_ value: Int) {
        print("return 0")
        self.value = value
    }
}

final class Return1: Return {
    var value: Int
    init(_ value: Int) {
        print("return 1")
        self.value = value + 50
    }
}

final class Return2: Return {
    var value: Int
    init(_ value: Int) {
        print("return 2")
        self.value = value + 500
    }
}

protocol FirstProtocol {
    init()
    func a() -> Return
    func b() -> Return
}

extension FirstProtocol {
    func a() -> Return {
        print("protocol a hello")
        return self.b()
    }
    
    func b() -> Return {
        print("protocol b hello")
        return Return0(5)
    }
}

enum Selector {
    case first, second
    
    func cls() -> FirstProtocol{
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return First1Class()
        case .second:
            return First2Class()

        }
    }
}

final class First1Class: FirstProtocol {
    init() {
        
    }
    
    func b() -> Return1 {
        print("first 1 class hello")
        return Return1(3)
    }
}

final class First2Class: FirstProtocol {
    init() {
        
    }
    
    func b() -> Return2 {
        print("first 2 class hello")
        return Return2(5)
    }
}

final class Runner {
    var cls: FirstProtocol
    var selector: Selector
    
    init(_ selector: Selector) {
        self.cls = selector.cls()
        self.selector = selector
    }
    
    
    func createCls(cls: FirstProtocol.Type) -> FirstProtocol {
        return cls.init()
    }
    
    func run(cls: FirstProtocol.Type) {
        print("--- run 1 ---")
        (self.createCls(cls: cls) as! First2Class).a()
    }
    
    func run2(t: Selector) -> Return {
        print("--- run 2 ---")
        print(t.cls())
        return t.cls().b()
    }
    
    func run3() -> Return {
        print("--- run 3 ---")
        print(self.cls)
        return self.cls.a()
    }
}

final class Runner2 {
    var runner: Runner
    
    init(runner: Runner) {
        self.runner = runner
    }
    
    func run() -> Return {
        print("--- 2run 1 ---")
        return self.runner.run2(t: .second)
    }
}

var a = Runner2(runner: Runner(.second)).run()
print(type(of: a))
print(a.value)
```

And returns below result.

```
--- 2run 1 ---                           line 1
--- run 2 ---                            line 2
__lldb_expr_80.First2Class               line 3
protocol b hello                         line 4
return 0                                 line 5
Return0                                  line 6
5                                        line 7
```

And here I have a question.

In `line 3` which is result of `Runner.run2`, I think `__lldb_expr_80.First2Class` string means compiler exactly knows which class should be initiated. Therefore `line 4` should be `first 2 class hello` not `protocol b hello`. Why `protocol b hello` is printed and how to make `first 2 class hello` is printed?

Comment: Your second question is too broad and is not suitable for stack overflow. You should not ask two questions in one post anyway. I suggest that you remove the second question.

Comment: @Sweeper Okay :) Thanks! I will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `b` in `First2Class` is not actually a witness for the `b` requirement in the `FirstProtocol` (same goes for `First1Class`). In other words, the reason why `First2Class` conforms to `FirstProtocol` is not the `b` method declared in it. The only witness for the protocol requirement is only the `b` in the protocol extension.

This is because the return types of these `b`s don't match the protocol requirement's return type:

```
// protocol requirement
func b() -> Return {
    ...
}

// First1Class
func b() -> Return1 {
    ...
}

// First2Class
func b() -> Return2 {
    ...
}
```

Return types must match exactly in order for a type to implement a protocol. See more discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094967/swift-how-can-i-make-a-function-with-a-subclass-return-type-conform-to-a-protoc).

When you call `b` on a protocol type, such as here:

```
return t.cls().b()
```

(`t.cls()` is of *compile-time type* `FirstProtocol`) because the `b`s are not the witness, your `b`s do not get considered when resolving the call. The call will only resolve to the only witness, which is the `b` in the protocol extension.

> ...means compiler exactly knows which class should be initiated.

That's not true. Remember that you only see the message printed at *runtime*. The compiler doesn't know which class is instantiated by `cls`.

Here is a shorter example that demonstrates this:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

protocol Foo {
    func foo() -> A
}

extension Foo {
    func foo() -> A {
        print("Foo")
        return A()
    }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    func foo() -> B {
        print("Bar")
        return B()
    }
}

let foo: Foo = Bar()
let bar = Bar()
foo.foo() // prints Foo
bar.foo() // prints Bar
```

Comment: Sorry for late :) I spent some time to understand. What I expected is that `Return1` conforms to `Return`, therefore `2Class.b() -> Return1` also conforms to `protocol.b() -> Return`. But in Swift, I should return exact same return type right?

Comment: @HyeonJunOh yes, see the linked discussion for more details.